# How to grant trust to an application programmatically or how to disable keygaurd from lollipop onwards?

Tags: android

I wanted to bypass the security lock when my application is on the top.Please explain how can we bypass the security lock from lollipop onwards. Disable keygaurd Api is not working from lollipop onwards. Please explain by giving examples codewise.

Comment: Do you solve your issue? Could you share some useful information